# Build Failure React Native - Evaluating Problem with Null Path

Tags: react-native

While runing my react native cli with npx react-native run-androind or expo cli method npm run androind both retrun this error back to me. And i don't know how to fix it, please help me. It looks pretty basic but i don't know my way out of it. I am stuck.

```
info Opening the app on Android...
info JS server already running.

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor


FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'E:\GitHub\likeminds\android\app\build.gradle' line: 21

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> path may not be null or empty string. path=''

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I have tried deleting and re-installing node. Added local.properties for SDK path, I have also make some few updates to the file path at settings.build. I was expecting the app to run on my device perfectly without error.

However error seems to lead to the build.gradle file on the dependencies. Is there an installation guide for dependencies for react-native?